# What does it mean to set the values of instance variables to the values passed in?

Tags: java, parameters, constructor

EDIT 4: I need to sleep so I'll be leaving this for a while, but I'll check it again tomorrow morning. I tried to press forward with the remaining directions but hit a road block here with step 4. I could not call setMonth, setDay, and setYear Here is step 4 and the remaining steps after it. Thanks for the help provided, it means a lot to this well-meaning newb. Cheers.

4. Rewrite the constructor from question 3 so that it calls setMonth(), setDay(), and setYear().  Build and run the project.  What is the output?
5. Write a set() method that has three parameters for the month, day, and year.  Uncomment lines 4 and 5.  Build and run the project.  What is the output?
6. Rewrite the constructor from question 3 so that it calls set ().  Build and run the project.  What is the output?

EDIT 2&3: I'm not sure if this is correct, but I added the following constructor to my code in the Date class. I retained the previous constructor, put this in below it, and now I don't get an exception.

```
public Date (int month, int day, int year) {

}
```

I also uncommented lines 2 and 3 from the DateTest class and added this code as well.

```
Date d = new Date(10,22,2014);
```

But I'm not sure if I did this right. I don't understand if what I did is setting the instance variables to the values passed in. My output is now the following:

```
Today’s date is 1/1/2000 
Today’s date is 0/0/0
```

EDIT 1: Thanks for the replies everyone. This is what I have tried:

```
public Date(int test1, int test2, int test3) {
 day = test1;
 month = test2;
 year = test3;
}
```

But then I get the following exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable
>   source code - constructor Date in class datetest.Date cannot be
>   applied to given types;   required: int,int,int   found: no arguments 
>   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length     at
>   datetest.DateTest.main(DateTest.java:12)

ORIGINAL POST:

I'm trying to figure out the instructions for my lab here and I got stuck on this part.

**3**.  Create a constructor that has three int parameters for the month, day, and year and sets the values of these instance variables to the values passed in.  Uncomment lines 2 and 3.  Build and run the project.  What is the output?

I know how to create a constructor, but I cannot figure out what to set the parameters to because I don't understand what it means by setting the instance variables to "the values passed in." I have completed the previous 2 steps which were:

**1**. Uncomment line 1 from DateTest (don’t forget to delete the “Line 1.” part) and build and run the project.  What is the output?  Why is this the output?

**2**.  Create a default constructor for Date which sets the date to 1/1/2000.  Build and run the project.  What is the output?

For the second step, I added the public Date() constructor right after the Date class is created.
Here is the code. I'm separing the two classes, this first one is the Date class.

```
package datetest;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Date
{
public Date() {
    month = 1;
    day = 1;
    year = 2000;
}
private int month;
private int day;
private int year; //a four digit number.


public void setYear(int newYear)
{
   year = newYear;
}
public void setMonth(int newMonth)
{
    if ((newMonth <= 0) || (newMonth > 12))
    {
        month=newMonth;
    }
    else
        month = newMonth;
}

public void setDay(int newDay)
{
    if ((newDay <= 0) || (newDay > 31))
    {
        day=1;
    }
    else
        day = newDay;
}

public int getMonth( )
{
    return month;
}


public int getDay( )
{
    return day;
}

public int getYear( )
{
    return year;
}

public void printDate( )
{
    System.out.print(getMonth() + "/" + getDay() + "/" + getYear());
}


public void readInput( )
{
    boolean tryAgain = true;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter month, day, and year.");
    System.out.println("Do not use a comma.");
    month = keyboard.nextInt( );
    day = keyboard.nextInt( );
    year = keyboard.nextInt( );
}

}
```

This is the DateTest class.

```
package datetest;


public class DateTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
Date today = new Date();

        System.out.println("Today’s date is " + today.getMonth() + "/" + today.getDay() + "/" + today.getYear());
        //Line 2. today = new Date(55, 55, 2011);
        //Line 3. System.out.println("Today’s date is " + today.getMonth() + "/" + today.getDay() + "/" + today.getYear());
        //Line 4. today.set(10, 5, 2011);
        //Line 5. System.out.println("Today’s date is " + today.getMonth() + "/" + today.getDay() + "/" + today.getYear());

 }
}
```

Comment: `instanceValue = passedInValue`...

Comment: Start by doing "a constructor that has three int parameters". Your constructor has no parameter at all right now. Once it has parameters, the rest should become obvious.

Comment: Your exception is saying that you are trying to call a constructor that takes 3 ints, but not passing any values to it. You need to overload the constructor, or remove the call Date today = new Date(); from the main program.

Comment: Thanks. How do I go about overloading the constructor? I don't want to remove the call Date today = new Date(); because that was prepared code provided to us students.

Comment: Overloading means changing functionality of a method (like a constructor) by changing the signature. So you can have a constructor Date() {...} that does your default values, and another constructor Date(int day, int month, int year) {...} where the values get assigned. Keywords for Google would be polymorphism and overloading.

Comment: Did I do it correctly? I edited my post above to show what I changed.

Answer (score 0):

The instance variables are the private members of your class :

```
private int month;
private int day;
private int year;
```

You are expected to write a constructor that accepts 3 parameters and assigns them to those instance variables.

Comment: Thanks for the replies everyone. I should have added, I tried to do this:

      public Date(int test1, int test2, int test3) {
       day = test1;
        month = test2;
        year = test3;
    }

But then I get a compile error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - constructor Date in class datetest.Date cannot be applied to given types;
  required: int,int,int
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
 at datetest.DateTest.main(DateTest.java:12)

Comment: @IAmTheWalrus If you are creating a constructor with arguments, you should call it with matching parameters - `Date d = new Date(1,1,1987);`

Comment: Sorry, can you explain this a little bit more? I'm having trouble comprehending what this means. Do I need to create another constructor in addition to the public Date() constructor?

Comment: @IAmTheWalrus Based on the requirements you posted, you need two constructors. One with no arguments and one with 3 arguments.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Should I add a line of code like the one you've provided to the Date or DateTest class? When I add it to either one, I get the exception that I edited in to the top of my post.

Comment: @IAmTheWalrus You should create the instance in DateTest. The exception you got suggests that you compiled one of your classes without compiling the other, and therefore, they don't match. You should compile both and try again.

Comment: I tried again and got the same thing. :( Do I need to uncomment the code marked Line 2 and Line 3 in DateTest? And if I need to add another constructor to the Date class, how do I go about that? I can't create another constructor because then I get an "invalid method declaration, return type required" error.

Comment: @IAmTheWalrus It looks like you should uncomment those lines. There shouldn't be a problem to define multiple constructors for the same class. A constructor doesn't require a return type, so perhaps your constructor has bad syntax or it's located in the wrong place.

Comment: Okay I think I'm getting somewhere. I added this line of code under my first Date constructor in the Date class: public Date (int month, int day, int year){} and now I don't get an exception.